# Can I use spring @PreAuthhorize annotation on any method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I started working on an existing spring boot application with spring security.
We have our resources authorized using with the @PreAuthorize annotation

I now have a new use case where I need to apply authorization when updating a collection within the resource

I mean. The logged in user may have permissions to update an entity, but he may not have access to update a collection within the entity

I read that enabling global method security I can put the authorization annotation on any method, so I tried putting it on a method that does the collection update. But it didn't work

Can I really use this annotation anywhere or should it be used only on controller bound methods?

I guess the question is whether this annotation is processed as a filter on a request or is it AOP?

I use it as follows:

```
  @Value
  private class FooDto {
    int id;
    String property1;
    Collection<Bar> bars;
  }

  @PreAuthorize("#id, 'FOO_RESOURCE:WRITE'")
  public FooDto update(int id, FooDto dto) {
    Foo foo = fooRepository.findBy(id);
    updateBars(dto.getBars(), foo.getBars());

    return updatedEntityDto;
  }

  @PreAuthorize("#id, 'BARS:WRITE'")
  private void updateBars(Collection<Bar> dtoBars, Collection<Bar> entityBars) {
    // update the collection
  }
```

Comment: it will work. show how u try

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib please see my update with the code example